# comparison in javascript confusion ie: (x === y (e))

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In Javascript how this pattern operates and by what name would you refer to it?

```
 var valid = (value === value2 (car.color));
```

And how is different from:

```
var valid2 = if(value === value2){ car.color }
```

Comment: That is called a boolean expression. Your second example won't even parse as valid Javascript, because `if` is a statement, not part of an expression. The operator you're using is called strict equality (i.e., equal value and equal type).

Comment: The first example `var valid = (value === value2 (car.color));` is also invalid JavaScript and will not parse. As stated below, if value2 is a defined function, then your example _will_parse, though the space between the function name and its parenthesized arguments is VERY non-standard.

Comment: Yes, the second will parse. `valid` will be assigned the result of the boolean expression.

Comment: @RobRaisch - The first example contains no syntax error.  http://jsfiddle.net/y1obbrjr/

Comment: @gilly3: Yes, as I noted, if `'function` === typeof value2`, you are correct. Though calling a function 'value2' is obfuscatory.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden: No, that will not parse since "= if(" is a violation of JavaScript parsing rules.

Comment: more than likely, given the title, the poster found this snippet in some obfuscated code where names wouldn't give any clues to the purpose of the functions, and tried to write out an equivalent function, not adhering to rules of spacing.

Comment: @Rob sorry I meant the first, in reply to your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't even close to the same.  In the first example, you have a function, `value2()`, which accepts a variable `car.color` as a parameter, returns something, which is then compared to `value`.  It's not exactly clear that `value2` is a function by the declaration or naming used in the code here, however, and the spacing doesn't help clarify it's purpose.

Your second example won't parse correctly, because you can't assign a variable to an `If` statement.  If it were possible, it still wouldn't make sense, because if `value == value2`, you enter a code block where the only statement is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `value2` is a function, so if `value2` returns something that is equal to `value` then `valid` is `true`, otherwise `false`. Your second statement, `var valid2 = if(value === value2){ car.color }`,
 however, is invalid JavaScript.